# Core Location - Property 'location' not found

Tags: xcode, core-location

Somewhere in my application I want to use 'user location'. I found the code below. However, I get a "property 'location' and 'delegate' not found" errors. The application is getting more complex, and I can't seem to find the solution. I'm new to xcode and objective-c. So will you please help me on that? 
Here is the code:

```
-(void)getUserLocation{

self.geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
self.locationMng = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationMng.delegate = self;

[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationMng.location completionHandler: 
 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {


     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];


     NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];


     NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);


    [locationLabel setText:locatedAt];

 }];

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you import `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` in that file?

Comment: @nekto yes, that was the first thing i checked.

Comment: How did you declare `locationMng `?

Comment: here : @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSObject *locationMng;

Comment: Omg! Thank you Nekto! I was looking for that for hours x|

Comment: @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet CLLocationManager *locationMng;

Comment: I sent the correct declaration of locationMng above.

Comment: Why do you need IBOutlet? It is only for xib objects.

Comment: Oops you're right it was unnecessary. I just got excited and immediately changed NSObject, then error was gone, so didn't look anything else :D accepted your answer. thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it follows from comments you have declared property `locationMng` incorrectly.

Try this:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationMng;
```